# Access to other state parts in reducer in ngrx

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I need to Remove a state value if another state part has changed. How should I access to other store parts from a reducer in NgRx?

my store schema:

```
a: {...}
b: {...}
```

I need to access from a reducer with 'a' feature store to 'b' feature store which is initialized in another reducer.

Comment: Please give more details. Where do you need access from ? And what do you need to access : a slice of store or a feature store ? Answer could be different.

Comment: @ThierryFalvo I need to access from a reducer with 'a' feature store to 'b' feature store which is initialized in another reducer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You resolve that with @ngrx/effects.

An Effect spies the action stream and filters for an action and react on it.

Your filter in the effect for the action, which changes the related part and dispatch an other action which changes the other part of the store. (you only have to return the new action to the effect)

```
@Injectable()
export class MovieEffects {

  loadMovies$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ActionsOfA.ChangeAction),    // which changes the related part
    map(action=>ActionsOfB.RemoveOtherPart  // dispatch
    )
  );

const aReducer = createReducer(initialState,
  on((ActionsOfA.ChangeAction, {payload}), state => ({...state, a: payload}))
);

const bReducer = createReducer(initialState,
  on(ActionsOfB.RemoveOtherPart, state => ({...state, b:{} )
);
```

In the filtered action there is also the payload, if you need it..

Comment: Thanks for your help, but  I need to access from a reducer with 'a' feature store to 'b' feature store which is initialized in another reducer

Comment: In the effect there are all Actions on the stream (a and b) and you can dispatch an action of an other reducer. I ajust the code. The only problem you can have if the feature stores are lazy loaded and the other store ist not loaded yet. Then you should not lazy load your b feature.

Answer (score 4):

Inside a reducer function, you can't access the state of another feature. This is normal and a good thing. Reducer are pure function.

As [official doc](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/reducers) mentioned :

> Reducers in NgRx are responsible for handling transitions from one state to the next state in your application. Reducer functions handle these transitions by determining which actions to handle based on the action's type.

Despite of that consideration, it's technically possible to :

- handle an action declared in feature B inside your reducer in feature A.
- set an effect for an action declared in feature B inside your feature A.

But be careful, even if it's possible, you should take care of your architecture, to avoid issues and ensure maintainability.

> I need to Remove a state value if another state part has changed. How
>   should I access to other store parts from a reducer in NgRx?

In this case, I recommend you to dispatch a new action to update state of feature B, when an action from feature A occurs, via an effect.

Let's take an example:

**Feature User**

- Action `UserActions.Load` is dispatched.
- In `User` reducer, `userState.loading` set to `true`
- An effect in `UserEffects`, handle `UserActions.Load` and dispatch a new action `UIActions.ShowNotification`.

**Feature UI**

- In `UI` reducer, `uiState.message` set to `...` received from `UIActions.ShowNotification(...)`
- An effect in `UIEffects`, handle `UIActions.ShowNotification` to show a snackbar...

Note that this won't work if your feature are in lazy loaded modules.

However, be very careful with this type of architecture to keep your code maintainable and well organized. 
Sometimes it is necessary to create another parent state or use `root` state. (exactly as in the case of circular dependencies).

Otherwise, note that you can also compose selectors for several features, thus avoiding modifying each state. (keep single source of truth)

```js
export const selectMessage = createSelector(
  selectLoading,  // from UserState feature
  selectMessage,  // from UiState feature
  (loading, message) => {
    return loading ? 'Loading...' : message;
  }
)
```